# Help using semphores and threads

Tags: c++, pthreads, buffer

I am using the pthread library to simulate a threaded buffer.  I am also using semaphores as a solution to accessing critical section variables one at a time.

The main problem is that the producer is filling the entire buffer and the consumer is then emptying the entire buffer.  Is this code correct? I was assuming that the production and consumption would occur before the buffer was full or empty.

Here is my code and any comments would help a lot, and yes this is for a class.

Thank you in advance

```
void *Producer(void *threadid) 
{
   long tid;
   tid = (long)threadid;

   while (c < Cycles)  //While stuff to buffer
   {                        
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);           
        while(size == BUFFER_SIZE)  
        {
           pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &lock);    
        }
     buffer [full] = rand();
     data << size+1 << ". Produce: " << buffer[full] << endl;
     printBuffer();
     full = (full + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE;
     size++;
     pthread_cond_signal(&cond1);
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
     c++;
   }
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

You can also download all the code or see the log file...

[download main.cpp](http://www.funkohland.com/pthreads/main.cpp)
view the log file at funkohland.com/pthreads/log.txt

Comment: Don't you mean mutex instead of semaphore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well known problem with Mutexes.  A Mutex is an expensive operation that requires lots of cycles.  When you unlock the mutex the other thread has a TINY opportunity in which to exit its lock and gain a lock.  Basially you need to spend less time in the mutex to give the other thread an opportunity to run.  Basically you need to choose the portion of code that ACTUALLY required the mutex and then lock the mutex quickly do whatever you need to do with that variable (and nothing more) and then unlock it.

Comment: Thank you, this explains alot

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you should ensure that access to shared variables 'c' and 'size' are carried inside a critical section. Thats between a lock and unlock calls. Currently you are freely accessing 'c' and sometimes 'size' without proper locking.

Comment: This is a great point I didnt even think about... I was just using c and cycles to not loop forever.  

is     size++; in a locked section?

Answer (score 0):

While Goz's answer is the reason, the possible solution is to yield to scheduler outside the mutex, either using `usleep(1)` or `sched_yield()`/`Sleep(0)` (depending on OS).

Also, since your producer uses rand(), it makes little difference but if it was using time-consuming I/O or advanced algorithms for making the new objects to be inserted, the right approach is to perform the actual production unmutexed, into a local buffer, then only mutex inserting the newly created object into the queue.

Comment: From my experience yielding very rarely gives enough time to the other thread for it to exit the mutex and then obtain the lock. I will maintain the real solution is to avoid spending so much time in the lock! :)

Comment: @Goz: In this case it would help a lot. Say, the producer spends 95% time inside the mutex. That means most of the times it will be scheduled out while the mutex is still locked. Consumer reaches mutex, finds it's locked, yields, producer gets CPU time again, exits mutex, reenters it, returns control, consumer is still locked and yields again... Of course if you reduce the time a thread spends under a mutex to ~50% (which is still a lot) it's a different story.

Comment: Thank you, I implemented your solution and the threads are now staggered instead of filling and emptying

Comment: @Scott: if it is too slow, yield only every nth iteration ( `if((c % REPEAT)==0) ...` ). @Goz: if the blocking thread releases lock and yields then the blocked thread that was waiting on blocking mutex, the first thing it receives control, will begin entering it, and since it's an atomic operation, it will not stop until it has the lock.